# GameCenter- Posting multiple achievements

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing game with GameCenter. In which after finishing a level player can complete more than one achievement. I would like to know can I post multiple achievements at the same time? If not what is the best practice to post achievements one after another.

Answer (score 0):

This document will be helpful.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html